# Set JComboBox height

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm not able to set the height of a `JComboBox`, I searched in the web but didn't found the right answer.

As you can see from the image below the combo box fills nearly all the panel height and I'd like it to have a smaller height.

I tried setting size with `getPreferredSize()` method but it didn't work, it worked only for other components like the button.

[image]

My code

```
  private JComponent firstPanel() 
  {       
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();        


    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel spesaAnnuaSingola = new JLabel();
    spesaAnnuaSingola.setText("Spesa Annua Singola");
    panel.add(spesaAnnuaSingola, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JComboBox<String> listaSpese = new JComboBox<String>();
    panel.add(listaSpese, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTextField speseAnnuaSingolaTF = new JTextField();
    speseAnnuaSingolaTF.setText("");
    speseAnnuaSingolaTF.setEditable(false); 
    panel.add(speseAnnuaSingolaTF, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    JButton button = new JButton("CALCOLA") 
    {
           public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
           {
                  return new Dimension(150,50);
            };
    };

    JPanel leftflowpanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
    leftflowpanel.add(speseAnnuaSingolaTF);
    panel.add(leftflowpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel rightflowpanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
    rightflowpanel.add(button);
    panel.add(rightflowpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    return panel;   
}
```

And then:

```
public StatsPanel()
{
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);     
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      // I will need a grid layout 
      this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 30, 30)); 
      JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 10, 20, 50));
      panelLeft.add(firstPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      this.add(panelLeft);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for the program? Makes it alot easier to identify what could be wrong! :)

Comment: @Tjernquist1 *"Can you post the full code for the program?"*  Oh please don't!  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JComboBox<String> listaSpese = new JComboBox<String>();
panel.add(listaSpese, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You add your combo box to the CENTER of the BorderLayout, which gets all the extra space of the frame. Don't add the combo box to the CENTER.

Instead you will need to nest panels. So create a panel for the NORTH of the BorderLayout. Then this panel will contain both your label and your combo box. Maybe use a vertical BoxLayout for this panel. Then both the label and the combo box will be displayed at their preferred heights.

Read the section from the Swing on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. The point is you can nest multiple panels each using a different layout to achieve your desired layout.